Is it possible to enable swipe-typing using a mouse on an on-screen keyboard in Windows 10, and if so, how can it be achieved to type faster?
Are there ways to achieve swipe-typing on an on-screen keyboard using mouse for Windows 10? Essentially, using the mouse for typing fast as well.
This is akin to swipe-typing on smartphones.
I think would be highly useful.

Your other question was closed as being off-topic. You should have fixed that answer and asked to have it reopened, rather than asking a very similar question again.

I did change it (to a presumably acceptable format) and resubmitted it, but didn't receive a review. I deleted the other post before reposting this one. If needed, I'll edit this one to be more acceptable.

You should ask here about a technical problem that you encounter as regarding computer hardware and software, which is what out site is about. This question might fit better in Software Recommendations.

Well noted. Thanks for your fruitful feedback. Clearly, I was lost.

So, for context, Swipe is a feature of the Windows On-Screen keyboard, but OP is specifically asking about allowing a Mouse cursor to be treated as a finger on the OSK so that they can swipe using the mouse. I'm guessing there may be testing modes available in Windows that may allow those. OP, you may want to look into a more generic question, such as "treat mouse pointer as touch input in Windows". That might help point you in the right direction.
